# How to block the return until a timer expires using RxJava

Tags: rx-java2

I'm not seeing anything ever get returned by the scan. I know it's because the mutableList gets returned right away, but how do I block the return until the time expires?

Basically, all I want to do is fill up the mutable list for as long as the take() permits then return that mutableList to the calling function.

This is what I have tried.

```
    private val timeoutScheduler: Scheduler = Schedulers.computation()

    fun scanForAllDevicesStartingWith(devicePrefix: String): List<String> {

       Log.d(TAG, "Scanning for devices starting with $devicePrefix")

       val mutableList = mutableListOf<String>()

       val result = scanForDevices()
           .take(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS, timeoutScheduler)
           .subscribe { scanResult ->
                val name = scanResult.bleDevice.name

                Logger.d(TAG, "Potential device named $name found")

                if(name != null) {
                    if(name.startsWith(prefix = devicePrefix)) {
                        Logger.d(TAG, "Match found $name")
                        mutableList.plus(name)
                    }
                }
            }

    return mutableList
}


private fun scanForDevices(): Observable<ScanResult>
        = rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(
        ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
                .build(),
        ScanFilter.Builder()
                .build())
```

}

Comment: Why not return Single<List<T>> and keep composing onto that, thus there is no need for blocking?

Comment: The caller of scanForAllDevicesStartingWith() needs to have all of the devices known before it can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here it is boiled down for the next person who wants to do this kind of thing. In Rx, they have Singles which are Observables that just emit one value. In my case I needed a list of String values, so just need to use a Single of type List of type String. That gets just one element emitted that happens to be a list of Strings. The code looks like this...

```
fun returnAllDevicesStartingWith(devicePrefix: String): Single<List<String>> {
return  scanForDevices()
   .take(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS, timeoutScheduler)
   .map { it.bleDevice.name }
   .filter { it.startsWith(devicePrefix) }
   .toList()
}
```

The function that calls it (written in Java instead of Kotlin) looks like this:

```
List<String> devices = bleUtility.returnAllDevicesStartingWith(prefix).blockingGet();
```

I tested it using a mocked function like this:

```
    //Begin test code
var emittedList: List<String> = listOf("dev1-1", "dev1-2", "dev2-1", "dev2-2", "dev3-1", "dev3-2")

private fun scanForRoomDevices(): Observable<FoundDevice> = Observable
        .intervalRange(0, emittedList.size.toLong(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, timeoutScheduler)
        .map { index -> FoundDevice(emittedList[index.toInt()], BleDevice(emittedList[index.toInt()])) }

data class FoundDevice(val controllerId: String, val bleDevice: BleDevice)
data class BleDevice(val name: String)
```

Hope this helps others.